# VTK error in Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, vtk

I'm new in vtk and I was trying to build the example code came with VTK 5.10.1.

The linker is giving me the following issues:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_vtkCocoaGLView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_BasicVTKView in BasicVTKView.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_vtkCocoaGLView", referenced from:
   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BasicVTKView in BasicVTKView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't have any idea what should be done.

Please help me.

Comment: Hello Raiyan - did you ever figure out what the problem was or what you changed to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My installation refer to the URL: [How to install VTK 6.1 for OSX 10.8 with Cocoa/XCode support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329258/how-to-install-vtk-6-1-for-osx-10-8-with-cocoa-xcode-support). After I use Angus Forbes's method, I meet the trouble just the same as yours posted above.

My solution as follows:
    [1] in xcode -> Project -> clean.
    [2]   (a) open termial, enter into the fold you build the VTK, eg. ~/VTK/VTKBuild.
          (b) make clean.

That's all. However, I don't know why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build the libvtkRendering with VTK_USE_COCOA=ON?
 Also there was a [mailing list](http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2010-May/109245.html) where problem was solved by adding IOKit framework to the project but personally I don't think its the reason. Anyway take a look at the mailing list