# VTK dyld: Library not loaded: libvtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2-7.1.1.dylib

Tags: c++, vtk

I try to learn VTK and when I execute the tutorials code it give me this error:

dyld: Library not loaded: libvtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2-7.1.1.dylib

Where is this library?

I use macOS Sierra and I install the vtk by this:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036019/setting-up-vtk-6-1-in-xcode-7-0-1)

Can you help me?

Comment: Your problem likely resembles the one I just described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697761/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper choice of cmake flags certainly will help solving your problem. Reading question and answer of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697761) may be helpful.

I am not fully convinced if you followed the referenced instructions exactly, because in the excerpt of the CMakeCache ([see here, point 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33036020/3388962)), `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` was disabled. However, your problem indicates that your binary was linked dynamically. Here I'm missing further details about your setup.

Let me maybe share the cmake command that I used to build vtk (with python wrapper and shared libraries). This worked for vtk 7.x.

```
mkdir build
cd build
INSTALL_DIR="/opt/dev/versions/vtk/vtk-7.1.0-shared"
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
         -DVTK_WRAP_PYTHON=ON \
         -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
         -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
         -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF \
         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$INSTALL_DIR" \
         -DCMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH=ON \
         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH="$INSTALL_DIR/lib" \
         -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/" \
         -DPYTHON_LIBRARY="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib"
make -j8
make install
```

Note that I had to set the python related flags to ensure that the correct python environment is used. (Often, there are multiple python environments available on a Mac: The python distributed by MacOS itself, a user python that was installed via homebrew or macports, or the framework that was acquired via [www.python.org](http://www.python.org). For me the third option applied.)